# (Unity) The Instantiate method seems to be blind to raycast normals, any idea?

Tags: unity-game-engine, quaternions, normals

I want to instantiate an object at the point a raycast hits an object, according to the surface's normal.

```
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && hit.collider != null) //thing placing condition
        {
            Instantiate(thing, hit.point, Quaternion.Euler(hit.normal));
        }
```

"hit" is the raycast hit information.

"thing" is what I want to instantiate.

When I try this code out, it appears that the method is blind to the normal of the object's surface the ray is colliding with (i.e. "Quaternion.Euler(hit.normal)" doesn't seem to affect the rotation argument of the instantiate method).

Are normals able to be used as rotational values? Is there a better way of placing objects according to a surface's normal?

Comment: Quaternion.Euler expects degrees per each axis (x,y,z), so values between 0 and 360. While hit.normal gives you the vector coordinates of the normal. So you are trying to use coordinates in a place that requires degrees.

Answer (score 0):

You likely want *LookRotation* because *Euler* expects angles and not an actual direction vector:

```
Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal, Vector3.up);
```